# Testing cross-contract calls

Tags: ink, nft

I'm in a situation where a user can mint new NFTs of a certain type B only if they are owner of NFT of type A. B NFT checks if caller has A NFT in a mint function. To instantiate a B contract I would need to pass A NFT address in the constructor.

The question is how do I get a hash of freshly created contract in test environment

```rust
        fn minting_works() {
            let accounts = default_accounts();

            let mut a_contract= AContract::new();
            set_sender(accounts.alice);

            a_contract.mint(cid.clone()); // Mint A NFT to a user
        

            let mut b_contract= BContract::new(contract_hash);
            b_contract.mint(cid.clone()); // Mint B NFT to a user
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This question has already been asked [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/28/how-to-test-cross-contract-ink-contracts). It looks like unfortunately there are at the moment no options to test your smart contract (when cross contract calling) in rust. In the github issue there is a mentoning of [redspot](https://github.com/patractlabs/redspot), but I don't know how well that would work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This answer [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/4379/2696) also contains more details on cross-contract testing. There are some new features that will be coming out soon to help make this process easier (such as exposing an API to a deployed contract).